# Batch file doesn't count my files in the C:\ but it does in D:\

Tags: batch-file

Batch file doesn't count my files in the **`C:\`** drive but it does in **`D:\`** drive.When I try to run the batch script it crashes if I am searching on **`C:\`** drive but it works on **`D:\`** drive.

```
@echo off

echo SNET File Finder [Versione 1.0]
echo Ricerca globale in tutto il disco D:\
echo.

:finderD
set /p fileD=Inserisci il file da cercare (con relativa estensione): 
echo.
echo Operazione in corso,potrebbero volerci alcuni secondi...
echo.

:findersystemD
cd /D D:\
dir /b %fileD% /s 2> nul | find "" /v /c > %tempD%\count
set /p countD=<%tempD%\count
del %tempD%\count
echo Sono stati trovati %countD% files:
echo.
dir /b %fileD% /s
echo.
pause
```

Comment: but there's `cd /D D:\` ?

Comment: how is `%tempD%` defined?

Comment: I would consider changing `cd /D D:\ ` to `CD /D D:\ 2>NUL||Echo D:\ non esiste&"%__AppDir__%timeout.exe" 5 /NoBreak>NUL`. This would at least let you know if the drive was mounted and available.

Comment: Thanks Compo,now it works,but it crashes if i do not run it as administrator,ho do i solve it?

Comment: There is nothing in the code, which would require it to be run "as administrator". That leaves only permissions as a possible reason.

Comment: Ok,anyway,thank you so much.

Answer (score 0):

This whole batchfile is about finding file on the D:\drive.

As far as working code is concerned, you can simply replace this line:

```
cd /D D:\
```

By this line:

```
cd /D C:\
```

However, I'd also advise you to do following replacements (for readability reasons):

```
Replace "il disco D:\"   by "il disco C:\"
Replace ":finderD"       by ":finderC"
Replace ":findersystemD" by ":findersystemC"
Replace "tempD"          by "tempC"
Replace "countD"         by "countC"
Replace "fileD"          by "fileC"
```

Good luck

Comment: Thank you,but still doesn't works,it crashes anyway

Comment: Where exactly does it crash, what do you see on screen?

Comment: It just closes the window,without saying anything

Comment: Then start by opening a command prompt (run `cmd`), navigate to the correct directory and start the batchfile there. What do you see?